# How can I get this globe visualisation(svg) to become responsive to different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, observable

**Languages:** Javascript, HTML and CSS.

**Frameworks:** D3.js

**link to code:** https://observablehq.com/@michael-keith/draggable-globe-in-d3

**Question:**

How can I get the globe visualisation to become responsive to different screen sizes?
e.g. at iphone globe width width = 200px at ipad globe width = 300px

First What I don't want is to set breakpoints to resize the `<svg>`

**What I've tried:**

I've tried using the attributes `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` e.g.

```
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
```

however, nothing happens.
my guess might be because of how the height and width are set. e.g.

```
let width = d3.select("#map").node().getBoundingClientRect().width
let height = 500
```

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using viewBox directly on the svg tag, without specifying width or height ? Your javascript should be able to pick the computed size anyway.